# Assigning a structure to another structure results in garbage

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

**The two structures used in my code, one is nested**

```
struct Class
{
    std::string name;
    int units;
    char grade;
};
struct Student
{
    std::string name;
    int id;
    int num;
    double gpa;
    Class classes[20];
};
```

I am trying to figure out a way to sort the structures within the `all_students[100]` array in order of their ID's in ascending order. My thought was, to start counting at position 1 and then compare that to the previous element. If it was smaller than the previous element then I would have a temporary array of type `Student` to equate it to, then it would be a simple matter of switching them places within the `all_students` array. However, when I print the results, one of the elements ends up being garbage numbers, and not in order. This is for an intermediate C++ class in University and we are not allowed to use pointers or vectors since he has not taught us this yet. Anything not clear feel free to ask me.

**The function to sort the structures based on ID**

```
void sort_id(Student all_students[100], const int SIZE)
{
Student temporary[1];
int counter = 1;
while (counter < SIZE + 1)
{
    if (all_students[counter].id < all_students[counter - 1].id)
    {
        temporary[0] = all_students[counter];
        all_students[counter] = all_students[counter - 1];
        all_students[counter - 1] = temporary[0];
        counter = 1;
    }
    counter++;
}
display(all_students, SIZE);
}
```

Comment: Not the downvoter, but you haven't provided a sample input that reproduces the error, or the code that calls your function. Both could be helpful in diagnosing the error.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but your O(n) function will  not perform a sort.

Comment: @DrewDormann it's not O(n)

Comment: @wolfPack88 you're right. I will keep that in mind for further questions. Sorry. I was just sure about the location of the error and I thought it would unnecessary to post main.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your code:

1. You don't need to create an array of size 1 to use as a temporary variable.
2. Your counter will range from 1 to 100, you will go out of bounds: the indices of an array of size 100 range from 0 to 99.

The following solution uses [insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) to sort the array of students, it provides a faster alternative to your sorting algorithm. Note that insertion sort is only good for sufficiently small or nearly sorted arrays.

```cpp
void sort_id(Student* all_students, int size)
{
    Student temporary;
    int i = 1;
    while(i < size) // Read my note below.
    {
        temporary = all_students[i];
        int j = i - 1;
        while(j >= 0 && temporary.id < all_students[j].id)
        {
            all_students[j+1] = all_students[j]
            j--;
        }
        all_students[j+1] = temporary;
        i++;
    }
    display(all_students, size);
}
```

**Note:** the outer while-loop can also be done with a for-loop like this:

```
for(int i = 1; i < size; i++)
{
    // rest of the code ...
}
```

Usually, a for-loop is used when you know beforehand how many iterations will be done. In this case, we know the outer loop will iterate from `0` to `size - 1`. The inner loop is a while-loop because we don't know when it will stop.

Answer (score 1):

Your array of Students ranges from 0, 99. Counter is allowed to go from 1 to 100.

I'm assuming SIZE is 100 (in which case, you probably should have the array count also be SIZE instead of hard-coding in 100, if that wasn't just an artifact of typing the example for us).

You can do the while loop either way, either

```
while(counter < SIZE)
```

and start counter on 0, or

```
while (counter < SIZE+1)
```

and start counter on 1, but if you do the latter, you need to subtract 1 from your array subscripts. I believe that's why the norm (based on my observations) is to start at 0.

EDIT: I wasn't the downvoter! Also, just another quick comment, there's really no reason to have your temporary be an array. Just have

```
Student temporary;
```

Comment: A very simple mistake, I suppose I deserved the downvote. thank you.

Comment: I actually had `Student temporary` at first but I was doubting whether that was causing issues so I changed it to be an array.

Answer (score 1):

I overlooked the fact that I was allowing the loop to access one more element than the array actually held. That's why I was getting garbage because the loop was accessing data that didn't exist.

I fixed this by changing `while (counter < SIZE + 1)`
to: `while (counter < SIZE )`

Then to fix the second problem which was about sorting, I needed to make sure that the loop started again from the beginning after a switch, in case it needed to switch again with a lower element. So I wrote `continue;` after `counter = 1`